# Update does not working while select returns right results

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-11g, update

I am trying to execute the query below:

```
UPDATE(
  SELECT Ord.Completed
  FROM Product P
  INNER JOIN Order1 Ord
  ON Ord.OrderID = P.OrderID
  WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM Delivery D
          WHERE Delivery.Delivered = 0 AND P.ProductID = Delivery.DeliveryID
        )
)
SET Completed= 'NO';
```

If I run the SELECT part only, without UPDATE it returns the right results. When I try to execute the UPDATE query I get

```
"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 250"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need `SET Completed= 'YES' ;` (remove the table name from that part)

Comment: @ypercube I tried it but I still get the same error. (Question Updated)

Comment: What should happen if an order has several products, some of them delivered and some not? Should the order br set as 'Completed'?

Comment: About the error, perhapos you are missing the statement separator (`;`). Not sure. But please answer the above question, I'm not sure your approach is correct.

Comment: I get the same error with the semicolon(`;`) too. An order has several products, some delivered and some other not. I add the Completed attribute to the Order table the 'YES' as the default value. An order is Completed when all its products are delivered. If I remove the UPDATE clause, the SELECT returns the correct results, that is, the Orders that contains products not delivered. I cannot understand why that's not work for the UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
UPDATE(
  SELECT Ord.OrderID, Ord.Completed
  FROM Order1 Ord
  WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM Product P
            INNER JOIN Delivery D
              ON Delivery.Delivered = 0 AND P.ProductID = Delivery.DeliveryID
          WHERE Ord.OrderID = P.OrderID
        )
)
SET Completed = 'NO' ;
```

or without a derived table:

```
UPDATE Order1 Ord
SET Completed = 'NO' 
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM Product P
          INNER JOIN Delivery D
            ON Delivery.Delivered = 0 AND P.ProductID = Delivery.DeliveryID
        WHERE Ord.OrderID = P.OrderID
      );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ypercube, your second solution worked fine for me. The first did not work, it returned the same error message but also the SELECT clause did not return correct data. I am running Oracle G11. Is there any possibility that it would run well in another rdbms such as mysql?

Comment: The 2nd query would run in mysql, the 1st no. I'll add more details in the answer later.

Comment: About right and wrong results, I can't say anything without same sample  data. It would be great if you could set up a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)